# MONTHS_BETWEEN error and to create flags

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-date-functions

```
SELECT months_between(TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD-MM-YYYY'),TO_DATE(DATE_COLUMN,'DD-MM-YYYY')) FROM TABLE_A;
```

1.I got an error which says, 'a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected'

Also, how to handle nulls.. I want to put a default date if the date_column is null in table_A.

2.

```
SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD-MM-YYYY'),TO_DATE(DATE_COLUMN,'DD-MM-YYYY')) FROM TABLE_A;
```

After calculating months between dates, I want to categorize the records with date range with a case statement..

For example..
if months_between for set of records is 22..I want to put a flag,'0-24', for all those records..
similarly, if months_between is 34.. I want to put a flag,'24-48', for all the records which fall under this range..

Comment: You don't need to convert SYSDATE, as per Gordon Linoff's answer. What datatype is DATE_COLUMN? If it's a date, as the name rather suggests, then you don't need to convert it either, and will get an error if you try to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to previous answer you can avoid null like this:

`SELECT months_between(trunc(SYSDATE), nvl(TO_DATE(DATE_COLUMN,'DD-MM-YYYY'), sysdate))`

If your `DATE_COLUMN` is date type than You don't need to use `TO_DATE()`

So You'll get somthing like this

`SELECT months_between(trunc(SYSDATE), nvl(trunc(DATE_COLUMN), sysdate))`

For the second part of Your question You may try something like this:

```
SELECT 
      trunc(months_between(trunc(SYSDATE),  trunc(DATE_COLUMN))),
      (trunc(months_between(trunc(SYSDATE),  trunc(DATE_COLUMN))/24)*24)||'-'||((trunc(months_between(trunc(SYSDATE),  trunc(DATE_COLUMN))/24)*24)+24)
FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to convert `sysdate` to a date.  Try this:

```
SELECT months_between(trunc(SYSDATE), TO_DATE(DATE_COLUMN,'DD-MM-YYYY'))
```

The problem is that the default format for a date in Oracle uses the month name.  When you say `to_date(sysdate, . . .)`, the first argument is converted to a string and then back to a date.

By the way, the `trunc()` is irrelevant, but you seemed to want to extract the day portion of `sysdate` so I left it in.

EDIT:

If `date_column` is already a date, just use:

```
SELECT months_between(trunc(SYSDATE), DATE_COLUMN)
```

Comment: Also, I don't think the query is giving the correct result..
for example..for a date, '27-APR-99', the query gives a result 22986.096..

Comment: Check the full value of the year on that date, there are 22986 months since the year 99 AD!

Comment: @user2942261 . . . This is then a problem with `date_column`.  If this is really stored as a date/time, then remove the `to_date()`:  `months_between(sysdate, date_column)` should be fine.  If it is stored as a string (as suggested by the code), then ask yourself why a date is being stored using the wrong data type.

Comment: Also see my comment under your question - it sounds like DATE_COLUMN is already a date, meaning it doesn't need to be converted.

Comment: you are correct.. I was trying to convert to_date which is already a date..now I got the correct result.. can you please answer 2nd part in my question..which is to create flags for date ranges..

Answer (score 0):

This works, if you have null values in the date_column and want to pass a default date.

`select months_between(SYSDATE,coalesce(DATE_COLUMN,to_date('01-01-2014','DD-MM-YYYY'))) DIFF from TABLE_A;`